# Compaq Presario a900 wireless driver for windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers

I am setting up a server for the first time and I am doing this in my old Compaq Presario a900 notebook.
To do that, I installed Windows Server 2008 in order to install a team system foundation server on top of it. My problem is that I can't use the wireless network.
Once I installed Windows, it recognized my adapter and installed a driver for it, but it isn't able to find any wireless networks, even though there is at least one available.

My wireless network adapter was recognized as Athero AR5007.

I looked for the drivers for windows server 2008 and I couldn't find. I also downloaded the Win7 version of this driver and tried to install, but I couldn't because I already have a the up-to-date driver.

Does anyone knows what can I do to get the wireless working?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the Wireless LAN Service feature? Check under Server Manager > Add Roles. It won't work without that configured.

Comment: It's not a role, it's a feature, and it's called `Wireless LAN Service`

Comment: didn't know that! I will check that out! thanks a lot!

Comment: that did it! Thanks a lot, you saved me many hours. It was indeed a server question after all :)

Comment: @Oscar not all server questions are on topic here.

Comment: @MDMarra ok, no problems. His answer and yours helped me a lot, I just wanted to thank you both :)